# jQuery click event not firing in Greasemonkey script

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I've appended an image to a page via GM and I'm trying to execute a click event to no avail.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Page markup contains:

```
<img id="kwdHelp" src="myImage />
```

Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script snippet...

```
function jQueryLoaded(){
    jQuery('#kwdHelp').click(function(){
    alert('clicked show help'); //DOES NOT FIRE
    });

    jQuery(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) 
    {
        if (event && event.target && jQuery(event.target).attr("class") == 'aw-ti-resultsPanel-details') 
        {
            if (waitToLoad !== null) 
            {
                window.clearTimeout(waitToLoad);
            }
            waitToLoad = window.setTimeout(SearchDomains, 100);
        }
    });
    setupLoadingImage();
};


function checkIfjQLoaded() {
   //if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { window.setTimeout(checkIfjQLoaded,100); }
    //else { jQuery = unsafeWindow.jQuery; jQueryLoaded();}
    jQueryLoaded();
};

checkIfjQLoaded();
```

Comment: When is jQueryLoaded() called ?

Comment: I've updated the question with more code, it appears that the developer I hired to do this script has commented out any check. Why not use $(document).ready(..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question should work (although it needs improvement, see below), assuming that the 2 undefined functions are really in the code somewhere.

Something that is not in the question is at fault.

- Link to the target page.
- Show the full, unedited code.
- What error messages does the Firebug console give?

---

Get rid of that `checkIfjQLoaded()` malarkey.  It's obsolete and poor practice.

Use `// @require` to load jQuery, and the script fires at `document.ready` by default.

Not only is the code simpler but it is much faster and more efficient, as it doesn't have to fetch jQuery every time.

The script would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$('#kwdHelp').click(function(){
    alert('clicked show help'); //DOES NOT FIRE
});

$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) 
{
    if (event && event.target && $(event.target).attr("class") == 'aw-ti-resultsPanel-details') 
    {
        if (waitToLoad !== null) 
        {
            window.clearTimeout(waitToLoad);
        }
        waitToLoad = window.setTimeout(SearchDomains, 100);
    }
});
setupLoadingImage();

function SearchDomains () {
    //...
}

function setupLoadingImage () {
    //...
}
```

Finally, if you want to use the script on Chrome, install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for best results.

Comment: Yes, I've got Tampermonkey running in Chrome. Greasemonkey in FF

Comment: The fix was to append .live('click',function(){

Answer (score 2):

Is the element present in the document at the time when you try to bind the event to it?

I usually do that mistake myself.